# How to stop manual swiping with PageView - controller.next() only?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I have a PageView which I'd like to stop a user being able to swipe on, and the only way to navigate through the pages is via PageController.next() and previous() methods.

I've tried setting the PageView physics to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() but that disabled all navigating of the PageView.

How can I configure the PageView to be navigable via code only?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it with IgnorePointer if there is no click event in those pages